# How to isolate (reserve) GPUs with identical hardware IDs via IOMMU / dracut / kernel parameters (in VoidLinux)

Tags: amd-graphics, pci, dracut, pci-passthrough, iommu

I'm trying to set up pci/gpu passthrough on void.
Specifically, using the `vfio-pci` driver to "reserve" one of the GPUs.
I have been following the procedure outlined in [this void-docs PR](https://github.com/void-linux/void-docs/pull/217) (and the arch wiki where relevant)

I have an RX 580 and an RX 570, and my groups allow for isolating the former:

```
IOMMU Group 0 - 11:
    dummy host bridges and such
IOMMU Group 12:
    03:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset USB 3.1 XHCI Controller [1022:43d5] (rev 01)
    03:00.1 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset SATA Controller [1022:43c8] (rev 01)
    03:00.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Bridge [1022:43c6] (rev 01)
    20:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43c7] (rev 01)
    20:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43c7] (rev 01)
    20:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43c7] (rev 01)
    22:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    25:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] [1002:67df] (rev ef)
    25:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] [1002:aaf0]
IOMMU Group 13:
    26:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] [1002:67df] (rev e7)
    26:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] [1002:aaf0]
IOMMU Group 14 - 19:
    dummy functions and audio devices
```

So, lumped in with a bunch of CPU-things, the RX570:

```
IOMMU group 12: 25:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] [1002:67df]
```

and completely separate, in its own group, the RX580:

```
IOMMU group 13: 26:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] [1002:67df]
```

Now as you can see these two share hardware IDs, and therefore I can't just specify a kernel param to push `vfio-pci` driver onto one of them, it would catch both of them. (as it would be described in the guide in the above pull-request)

I tried separating them [following the guidelines on the arch-wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Using_identical_guest_and_host_GPUs), added the "Passthrough selected GPU" script to my dracut config:

`/usr/local/bin/vfio-pci-override.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

DEVS="0000:26:00.0 0000:26:00.1"

if [ ! -z "$(ls -A /sys/class/iommu)" ]; then
    for DEV in $DEVS; do
        echo "vfio-pci" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/$DEV/driver_override
    done
fi

modprobe -i vfio-pci
```

`/etc/dracut.conf.d/10-vfio.conf`

```bsh
hostonly=" yes "
hostonly_cmdline=" amd_iommu=on iommu=pt "
force_drivers+=" vfio_pci vfio vfio_iommu_type1 vfio_virqfd "
install_items+=" /usr/local/bin/vfio-pci-override.sh "
```

which should have an effect, if I'm not mistaken, if I run `xbps-reconfigure --force linuxX.Y`
but for some reason, the `amdgpu` driver still catches both GPUs.

I have the following kernel parameters set in the `/etc/default/grub` file:

```bsh
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=4 amd_iommu=on iommu=pt rd.driver.pre=vfio_pci"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, and will be forwarded to the aforementioned PR to extend on the guide.
(Though I know the void handbook isn't meant to describe things like this in detail, but maybe it'll be useful for the creation of an independent guide on this)

Answer (score 0):

I also tried the Arch guide without any luck. when I got to the bottom of this page I was sadden to see no solution.

Ubuntu/Kubuntu 20.04 I have this working without issue, but the same hardware under Manjaro no dice.

The difference is initramfs-tools vs mkinitcpio (or in your case dracut)

here is my reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/tjjb9g/switched_from_kubuntu_to_manjaro_kde_minimal_lts/